# NextJs postcss.config error with Tailwind CSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, postcss, npm-build

I'm trying to deploy my NextJs Application on O2Switch and Cpanel.
I have a Tailwind config for this app. Here you can see my Tailwind setup files:

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

     const { fontFamily } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

     module.exports = {
    content: [
      // Or if using `src` directory:
      "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    ],
    darkMode: 'class',
    theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        mont: ['var(--font-mont)', ...fontFamily.sans],
      },
      colors: {
        dark: "#1b1b1b",
        light: "#f5f5f5",
        primary: "#B63E96", // 240,86,199
        primaryDark: "#58E6D9", // 80,230,217
      },
      animation: {
        'spin-slow': "spin 8s linear infinite"
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        circularLight:
        "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 2px,#f5f5f5 5px,#f5f5f5 100px)",

      circularDark:
          "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 2px,#1b1b1b 8px,#1b1b1b 100px)",

      circularLightLg:
          "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 2px,#f5f5f5 5px,#f5f5f5 80px)",

      circularDarkLg:
          "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 2px,#1b1b1b 8px,#1b1b1b 80px)",

      circularLightMd:
          "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 2px,#f5f5f5 5px,#f5f5f5 60px)",

      circularDarkMd:
          "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 2px,#1b1b1b 6px,#1b1b1b 60px)",

      circularLightSm:
          "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 2px,#f5f5f5 5px,#f5f5f5 40px)",

      circularDarkSm:
          "repeating-radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 2px,#1b1b1b 4px,#1b1b1b 40px)",
      }
    },
    screens: {
      "2xl": { max: "1535px" },
      // => @media (max-width: 1535px) { ... }
  
      xl: { max: "1279px" },
      // => @media (max-width: 1279px) { ... }
  
      lg: { max: "1023px" },
      // => @media (max-width: 1023px) { ... }
  
      md: { max: "767px" },
      // => @media (max-width: 767px) { ... }
  
      sm: { max: "639px" },
      // => @media (max-width: 639px) { ... }
  
      xs: { max: "479px" },
      // => @media (max-width: 479px) { ... }
      },
     },
      plugins: [],
     }
```

**postcss.config.js**

```js
    module.exports = {
     plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
     },
    }
```

**src/styles/globals.css**

```css
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
```

**src/pages/_app.js**

```js
    import '@/styles/globals.css'
    import { Montserrat } from "next/font/google"

     const montserrat = Montserrat({
       subsets: ["latin"],
       variable: "--font-mont"
     });
```

**package.json**

```json
    {
      "name": "test",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": false,
      "scripts": {
      "dev": "next dev",
      "build": "next build",
      "start": "next start",
      "lint": "next lint"
     },
     "dependencies": {
      "eslint": "8.36.0",
      "eslint-config-next": "13.2.4",
      "framer-motion": "^10.6.0",
      "next": "13.2.4",
      "react": "18.2.0",
      "react-dom": "18.2.0",
      "sharp": "^0.32.0"
     },
      "devDependencies": {
      "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
      "postcss": "^8.4.21",
      "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1"
     }
    }
```

And now my problem :
On my Cpanel, I'm importing in my sub-domain the git repo of my project, then I use "Setup Node.js App" to create the environment.

Using a "PuTTY" terminal, I run `npm install`. All is OK. Then I try `npm run build` and I get this error:
[image]

The only way to avoid this problem is to delete my `postcss.config.js` file. But without this file Tailwind is disabled and my website looks absolutely horrible.

I'm stuck on this for 2 days. Have you got any idea?
(On my Cpanel I'm using the highest node version possible, v16.19 (v18 is not working, I don't know why).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing a closing double-quote at the end of line 2 of `src/pages/_app.js`. It should be:

```js
import { Montserrat } from "next/font/google"
```

You may also need to change your import path from

```js
import '@/styles/globals.css'
```

to

```js
import '@styles/globals.css'
```

Comment: That's a mistake when i wrote here, but you right. Anyway, it doesn't solve my issue ^^

Comment: You should edit your question and fix it there at least.

Comment: I added another possible fix for your import path.